# Geometry is missing from Layout view?

Tags: 3d-view

New Blender user here. I cannot for the lift of me figure out why the 4 pieces of geometry in the Frame collection are not showing up in the Layout 3D viewport? As far as I can see they are not hidden (the Eye icon is active). And they show up in the render. But I cannot see or interact with them.

Why?

From the "Layers" panel it seems to me that everything should be visible. Why are the Camera, Light and Plane (Floor) visible?

[Download Blend file](https://file.io/a3iQyH6mOYuP)

[image: Blender Layout]

Comment: maybe share your blend file so we can check it out?

Comment: I've added a link

Comment: Maybe you have a graphic driver problem - i can see them [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvbmD.png

Comment: Link reports that "The transfer you requested has been deleted". Files should be shared via the official site if they're small enough: https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to add the link to the file.